# Vertically align set of elements

Tags: html, css

I'm designing my layout for my Pong game and am having trouble with aligning the elements in the bottom of my page so they're all on the same horizontal line. Underneath the playing arena I have my scoreboard, with the instructions to the left, and a Play button to the right, which should all be on the same line next to each other.

The instructions and scoreboard are fine, but for some reason the Play button is place on the bottom right of the inline display, instead of the middle.

[Here is a JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nbanjwwp/)

and my html:

```
<body>
<div id="back">

    <div id="arena">
        <div id="paddleL" class="paddle"><div id="hitZoneL"></div></div>
        <div id="paddleR" class="paddle"><div id="hitZoneR"></div></div>
        <div id="ball"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="instructions">
        <h3> Instructions: </h3>
        <h3> Space to launch </h3>
        <h3> Buttons: up/down </h3>
    </div>
    <div id="scoreboard">
        <h1> Score </h1>
        <h2 id="leftScore"> 0 </h2>
        <h2 id="rightScore"> 0 </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="loginDiv">
        <button id="loginButton" onclick="login()">Play!</button>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
```

and the css:

```
body {
    background-color: rgba(40, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

h2 {
    display: inline;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
}

#instructions {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 100px;
}

#loginDiv {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    right: 250px;
}

#loginButton {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 80px;
    font-size: 30px;
}

#leftScore {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10%;
}

#rightScore {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10%;
}

#back {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100vw;
}

#arena {
    width: 1200px;
    height: 650px;
    background-color: rgba(00, 99, 0, 0.2);
    border: 2px solid black;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.paddle {
    position: absolute;
    height: 90px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: black;
}

#paddleR {
    right: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 40%;
    border-top-right-radius: 40%;
}

#paddleL {
    left: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 40%;
    border-top-left-radius: 40%;
}

#scoreboard {
    border: 4px solid black;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: rgba(00, 0, 99, 0.2);
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

As you can see if you zoom out, the play button is in this position:
[image: defaultImage]

Is there any way to make it go more towards where the black box is in this picture, so its vertically aligned with the middle of the scoreboard?
[image: Wanted]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `position:absolute` needs to be in relationship to something; right now, it's aligning things in relationship to the body, but you'd probably be better off putting a wrapper div around `#instructions` `#scoreboard` and `#loginDiv` and positioning against that. Once you've created this wrapper div (I've named it `#footer` in my [CodePen](http://codepen.io/angeliquejw/pen/zqwrNy?editors=1100), you'll want to update your CSS with the following :

```
#footer {
    /* This assures that the absolutely positioned child elements will base their positioning off of this div */
    position:relative;

    /* Styles to match #arena */
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 1200px;
}

#instructions {
  position: absolute;
  /* Position in relationship to #footer */ 
  top:0;
  left: 100px;
}
#loginDiv {
  position: absolute;
  /* Position in relationship to #footer */ 
  top:40px;
  right: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For some reason when I try implementing your solution my instructions and login float towards the top like this: http://i.imgur.com/2mnBh6R.png. I'm going to try debug though and I'll see what my problem is.

Comment: Well I just copy and pasted your whole css from the Codepen and now it works. Before I just copied the css you gave in this page. Thanks so much!

Comment: I had reversed the asterisk and slash in my comment underneath `#footer`, which led to the `position:relative` being commented out. If you fix that, should be good to go :)

Answer (score 2):

You're `#scoreboard` also needs to be an `inline-block`.